# How do I pick multiple blocks of text in a text file using regex in python3

Tags: regex, python-3.7

I am trying to build a regex to collect blocks of text from a log file.

Its structure is as follows:

```
Section Start indicator
-
   Few lines of text. Not needed
-
- Block start indicator
- Block end indicator
-
   Few lines of text. Not needed
-
- Block start indicator
- Block end indicator
-
   Few lines of text. Not needed
-
-- repeat
Section End indicator

- Must not include any blocks from this section
Section Start indicator
-
   Few lines of text. Not needed
-
- Block start indicator
- Block end indicator
-
   Few lines of text. Not needed
-
- Block start indicator
- Block end indicator
-
   Few lines of text. Not needed
-
-- repeat
Section End indicator
```

I have tried to use the following

```
(Block start indicator.*?Block end indicator)
```

This works fine with "Single line" and "Global" flag set. However, the information above is duplicated in the log file. So I wish to use the **Section Start Indicator** and **Section End Indicator** to only capture the first instance of the text section.
However here I cannot figure out the correct regex construct.
I've tried:

```
Section Start Indicator.*?(Block start indicator.*?Block end indicator).*?Section End Indicator
```

This only captured the first block in the section. I tried to make it look for multiple instances of my block capture group:

```
Section Start Indicator.*?(?:(?:(Block start indicator.*?Block end indicator).*?)+).*?Section End Indicator
```

I had to remove the Global flag because it also captured the repeated data.

So to recap:

- I have a large text section that is repeated throughout the log
  file. But I want to capture only the first instance using
  the start and end indicators.
- In this large section contains a few smaller lines of text also with start and end indicators.
  I need to capture these lines.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

We can use a negative look ahead to make sure that we do not have a second block start in the middle of the block.

```
Block start indicator((?!Block start indicator).)+Block end indicator
```

see https://regex101.com/r/Q0090l/1

Comment: I might have explained it wrong. But https://regex101.com/r/6jIclm/1 shows how the log is, I'm only interested in the Block ( all of them ) in the first section only